Chrome Extension Dropdown changes Popup size when opened
So I am making an extension with a dropdown menu, but because I want to control the text better than with a select, I want to make a custom one with div's.
Now the select-tag does not make any problems, as you can see, it displays outside of the extension, but when I try to display the custom one, it expands the popup:


I tried to put this in a minimally reproducible example, which I also put into an extension:


As you can see the :root size does not change, but it still expands the popup. How is this possible? What am I doing wrong? The parent is relative, the child absolute, is that not correct?


function toggleDropdown() {
  document.getElementById("dropdownMenu").classList.toggle("show");
}

document
  .getElementById("selectorContainer")
  .addEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);
:root {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px;
}

.selector-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selector-menu {
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.selector-menu.show {
  display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 8px;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="selector-container" id="selectorContainer">
      Selected Language
      <div class="selector-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
        <div class="menu-item">Detect Language</div>
        <div class="menu-item">English</div>
        <div class="menu-item">German</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




The problem is that you are not removing the CSS property of display: none;

No, it's the same with the property entirely removed. It gets overwritten by
.selector-menu.show {
display: block;
}
doesn't it?

You can't show an element outside of the physical borders of the popup because the popup is a separate floating window shown on top of the browser. Only the native select element can do that because it's shown by the OS itself.

ok thanks a lot! Is there a ressource that describes this? I didn't find anything previously :(
